# Function returning ad-hoc object in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Currently I have a private function which returns a `Pair<User, User>` object. The first user is the sender of something, the second user is the receiver of that thing.

I think this `Pair<User, User>` is not enough self explanatory - or clean if you like - even though it's just a private function.

Is it possible to return with an ad-hoc object like this:

```
private fun findUsers(instanceWrapper: ExceptionInstanceWrapper): Any {
    return object {
        val sender = userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.fromWho)
        val receiver = userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.toWho)
    }
}
```

and use the returned value like this:

```
// ...
val users = findUsers(instanceWrapper)
users.sender // ...
users.receiver // ...
// ...
```

?

If not, what's the point of ad-hoc object in Kotlin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the type can not be denoted in the language, use return type inference:

```
class Example {
    private fun findUsers(instanceWrapper: ExceptionInstanceWrapper) =
        object {
            val sender = userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.fromWho)
            val receiver = userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.toWho)
        }

    fun foo() = findUsers(ExceptionInstanceWrapper()).sender
}
```

Another option would be to devise a data class:

```
class Example {
    private data class Users(val sender: User, val receiver: User)
    private fun findUsers(instanceWrapper: ExceptionInstanceWrapper): Users {
        return Users(
            sender = userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.fromWho),
            receiver = userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.toWho)
        )
    }

    fun foo() = findUsers(ExceptionInstanceWrapper()).sender
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I really like how the authors of the language work hard for creating an active community. I wanted to avoid declaring a class only for this usage, so I prefer the first solution. Awesome language.

Comment: Worth mentioning that also with the first example you are not limited to only create an object. You can add an init scope to the object to do whatever other work you need.

Answer (score 2):

Simply define your function as a lambda.

Here's simple object I've just written as an example in another context:

```
private val Map = {
    val data = IntArray(400)

    for (index in data.indices) {
        data[index] = index * 3
    }

    object {
        val get = { x: Int, y: Int ->
            data[y * 20 + x]
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val map = Map()
    println(map.get(12,1))
}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot assign a type name, so it can be used as a return value but not as an argument. Maybe they'll make this possible so we can finally do OOP JS style.

Alternatively, they could implement object types equivalent to function types but that could end up being too wordy. You could then do a typedef but that would actually just be a kind of class definition

Comment: Nice. However AFAIU you cannot pass parameters to this lambda. To pass parameters you would need to explicitly declare its type, which you cannot do because you do not have the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have a generic class for return types:

```kotlin
data class OutVal<T>(private var v: T?) {
    fun set(newVal: T) {
        v = newVal
    }

    fun get() = v
}
```

Usage example:

```kotlin
private fun findUsers(instanceWrapper: ExceptionInstanceWrapper,
                      sender: OutVal<String>, receiver: OutVal<String>) {
        sender.set(userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.fromWho))
        receiver.set(userCrud.findOne(instanceWrapper.toWho))
}

val sender = OutVal("")
val receiver = OutVal("")
findUsers(instanceWrapper, sender, receiver)
sender.get() // ...
receiver.get() // ...
```